# How to handle cache since the cache package is not available for flutter version 2 in pub.dev

Tags: flutter, caching, bloc

The Code above shows a section from bloclibrary.dev [Complete Code example on BlocLibrary.dev](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial?id=setup) on how to build the UI for login screen using bloc and Firebase. Since there is no available version of cache in pub.dev, I do not know how to replace the `CacheClient` variable properly.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:authentication_repository/authentication_repository.dart';
import 'package:cache/cache.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebase_auth;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

/// Thrown if during the sign up process if a failure occurs.
class SignUpFailure implements Exception {}

/// Thrown during the login process if a failure occurs.
class LogInWithEmailAndPasswordFailure implements Exception {}

/// Thrown during the sign in with google process if a failure occurs.
class LogInWithGoogleFailure implements Exception {}

/// Thrown during the logout process if a failure occurs.
class LogOutFailure implements Exception {}

/// {@template authentication_repository}
/// Repository which manages user authentication.
/// {@endtemplate}
class AuthenticationRepository {
  /// {@macro authentication_repository}
  AuthenticationRepository({
    CacheClient? cache,
    firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth,
    GoogleSignIn? googleSignIn,
  })  : _cache = cache ?? CacheClient(),
        _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth.instance,
        _googleSignIn = googleSignIn ?? GoogleSignIn.standard();

  final CacheClient _cache;
  final firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the CacheClient implementation here:

https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_firebase_login/packages/cache/lib/cache.dart

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30722711)